# Create Activity that looks like PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, styles, preferenceactivity

I need to make an Activity that will replace the PreferenceActivity. The reason is that we need to save the settings in the SQL. I need a way to style my settings screen to look exactly like the PreferencesActivity. Can someone give me a link to the code of the PreferenceActivity layout code on Android AOSP? or maybe how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why do you wanna replace it? You can save the settings in SQL with the PreferencActivity as well.

Comment: Take a look at the official documentation or the Android Training. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html